# Properties of determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove using properties of determinants :
\begin{equation*}
\left|\begin{matrix}
b^2 + c^2 & a^2 & a^2\\
b^2 & c^2 + a^2 & b^2\\
c^2 & c^2 & a^2 + b^2
\end{matrix}\right| = 4a^2b^2c^2
\end{equation*}

Comment: Do you care to add the question statement to the question body here? Also, might you tell us what you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: Usually questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  If you want to ask about a homework problem, you can say specifically where you ran into difficulty with it, or ask for help understanding the question. $\qquad$

Comment: Try by  expanding along a row  or column

Comment: Some properties you could try to use are elementary row/column operations. Adding a multiple of a row/column to another leaves the determinant unchanged. Multiplying a row/column by a scalar changes the determinant by a factor of that scalar. Swapping two rows/columns changes the sign of the determinant.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate a determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix, you need to choose a reference row/column first. Let's say we choose to calculate the determinant along the first row.

Then you need to cross out the first row and first column and calculate the determinant of the remaining $2\times 2$ matrix, which is $(c^2+a^2)\times(a^2+b^2)-b^2\times c^2$. And then you multiply this with the chosen element, which is the intersecting element of first row and first column. In this case, $b^2+c^2$. And then you multiply the whole chunk by either $1$ or $-1$.

The way to choose either $1$ or $-1$ would be as follow:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & -1&1\\
    -1&1&-1 \\
    1&-1&1
\end{bmatrix}

If you follow this to calculate along the first row, and add them up together, you would have

$(b^2+c^2)\times[(c^2+a^2)\times(a^2+b^2)-b^2\times c^2]-a^2\times[b^2(a^2+b^2)-b^2\times c^2]+a^2\times [b^2\times c^2-c^2(c^2+a^2)]$

And if you clean this up, you would get $4a^2b^2c^2$